# Pmf of a number of balls where bucket has a certain capacity.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions, markov-chains, random

There are $n$ buckets, each with a possibly different finite capacity $c_i \; (i=1, \dots, n)$. There are
$k$ balls, each to be distributed randomly to the buckets.
A bucket cannot be filled over its capacity.
I would like to know the pmf of the number of balls that bucket $i$ receives.

I saw this post, [Probability of assigning balls into buckets, where each bucket has a certain capacity.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/896880/probability-of-assigning-balls-into-buckets-where-each-bucket-has-a-certain-cap), but it doesn't quite capture what I want. I thought about just using a Markov chain, but there could potentially be too many states in the probability transition matrix for my problem. It would grow exponentially fast.

Is there a formula for the pmf of the number of balls that bucket $i$ receives?

Edit: If it was not clear, initially buckets are chosen uniformly at random, and when a bucket reaches its capacity, it drops out and buckets are chosen uniformly at random from those buckets not yet filled.

Comment: I want to be sure I understand the distribution mechanism.  I take it that initially, buckets are chosen uniformly at random, and when a bucket reaches its capacity, it drops out and buckets are chosen uniformly at random from those buckets not yet filled.  Is that right?

Comment: @saulspatz Yes, that is exactly right.

Comment: I'm thinking that perhaps ordering the buckets by their capacities would be helpful, but I'm not sure.